# How auto set "diredc" mode when start Emacs?

Tags: dired

Linux Mint 20.1

Emacs 26.3

I install package "**diredc**". https://github.com/Boruch-Baum/emacs-diredc

To start in I use: `M-x diredc`

Nice. It's work fine.

But problem is when I restart Emacs I need again execute `M-x diredc` to switch it  diredc mode.

Is it possible to autoset diredc mode when run Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

It should be no different than auto-starting any other emacs package, so you should be able to add a snippet to your emacs' init file to do what you want:

1. The "old" way would be to use elisp command `require` to force loading of the package, and then maybe add commands to assign key-bindings, and maybe start an instance of it;
2. The fashionable "new" way that all the cool kids have started using would be to use elisp package `use-package` and go to town with all its features for configuring and and assigning keybindings and and what-not.